# Plywood sealer paint coated

Tags: plywood

Hi I bought new fence 3 weeks ago its fresh cut and delivery to here it like sort like green not brown wood and I guess that wood very fresh cut will it be ok to paint sealer dark walnut on it or should I wait 3 months to paint sealer ?? Please let me know .. Brett

Comment: Freshly cut lumber is referred to as 'green' although the color is not green.  Newly treated lumber for exterior use is often tinted somewhat green in color due to the chemicals it has been bathed in. Was your fence material tagged as moisture treated lumber? (There is often a small plastic label stapled to the material or the supplier can confirm the type of wood used.)   If so it will turn brown as the moisture from the treatment process evaporates.

Comment: Can I  paint sealer now ??

Comment: Still  no reply sigh  :(

Comment: Sorry, I was out of town.  I am not sure what you mean by 'green'.  Are you talking about color or wetness.  What kind of paint/sealer are you applying?  If the wood is dry you should be able to apply a finish.

Comment: Your best bet would be to contact the company that created the fence and ask them for maintenance info. Since we don't know what was done to this fence, we would at least need a clear photo or two showing the existing finish and maybe any identifying marks. But it's hard to see this question as on-topic for WW.SE, as it appears to be more suited for DIY or construction SEs.